# Combination Strategy

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, combinations

In fantasy baseball you have 8 batter slots to fill and you can have no more than 4 players from the same team. How can you figure out what stacking combinations (4x4),(3x3x2)... etc goes best with slate size(number of games on a certain night) or would it be better to compare combinations with the total number of players in the pool?

edit:

**Scoring:**
single = 3pts, double = 6pts, triple = 9pts, HR = 12pts, RBI = 3.5pts Run= 3.2pts, walked = 3pts, stolen base = 6pts, HBP = 3pts

**Salary constraint:** 60k

**info used for score project:** maximize variance and average for each player and try to stack as many players who are positively correlated with one another. Positively correlated in the fact that they all share common resources and players who are consecutive in the batting order will be positively correlated i.e. if you have a batter in the first position then you want as many consecutive batters as your constraints allow because his potential is somewhat reliant on the player that comes after him.

Ideally I want to be able to say,

4x4 stack has the highest output when slate size is 9 games(144 batters)

4X3 stack has the highest output when slate size is 6 games(90 players)

etc...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any knowledge of baseball -- what do you mean by "goes best with"? and when you say "stacking combination" are you referring to the number of ways you can choose 8 players from among the number of different teams such that no more than 4 are of the same team -- if so, how many total teams do you have to decide between, and do you care about differences in the players themselves within a team?

Comment: @JackCrawford so goes best with meaning that the combination of players produces the highest fantasy score. and the answer to question is yes for stacking combination. slate size changes daily. some days there's 6 games others there's 15

Comment: also players will be restricted by salary($60,000) - pitcher salary.

Comment: Well, ok -- how are the fantasy scores calculated? What information do you have about the players and how does that relate to the score they generate? This seems like quite a complicated problem but you're not giving us much information to work with.

Comment: @JackCrawford updated the post.

Comment: I suggest you test your combinations using a sports betting simulator, with real time data (but virtual money),  before you decide on the optimal combinations.  http://ospisoft.com/project/betsim/  Many more available out there (Google Play has one too). Good luck.